# delete n-th character from string

Tags: java, replace, char

There is a String "Saya"
I want to delete 4th character so it will be "Say"

I already do this

```
String word = "Saya";
char c = word.charAt(3);
String delete = Character.toString(c);
String newWord = word.replace(delete,"");
System.out.println(newWord);
```

But the result is "Sy". It delete all character that same with 4th

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Youre deleting both instances of the character `a`

Comment: Do you want to specifically just delete the nth character in a string?

Comment: @jamis0n Yes. That what I mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use [substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).  Like so:

```
i = 3;
String newWord = word.substring(0,i)+word.substring(i+1);
```

Make sure you check the length of your original string otherwise you may get an IndexOutOfBoundsException